# k-textbox input in html create event template not reflecting value change in javascript (kendo scheduler)

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have an html input that has the k-textbox class to make it a kendo styled input textbox:

```
<input id="LocationInput" class="k-input .k-textbox" data-bind="value:location"/>
```

Then, when I open the create event popup (which is where the location input text box is located) and I have a user specified parameter for LocationInput with a value they wish to autofill....

I do `$('#'+paramData[i].fieldName+'Input').val(paramData[i].recordId);`

where paramData is an array of passed parameters, fieldName would be 'Location' and recordId would be its value. After this, the text is set correctly in the console when checked with console.log, but no changes are reflected in the create event popup, the box is still empty. I tried adding a '.change()' after the '.val()' but that didn't do anything either.

How can I get the 'k-textbox' input to reflect the value I set it to in the javascript when the input is part of the create event template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the input you should search within the container element of the event object that gets passed to your handler:

```
function yourSchedulerAddOrEditEventHandler(e) {
    e.container.find('#'+paramData[i].fieldName+'Input').val(paramData[i].recordId);
    e.container.find('#'+paramData[i].fieldName+'Input').trigger("change");
}
```

See here for more info http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#events

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. However, that ended up only reflecting changes in the create popup input fields themselves, and not in the actual event, so simply had to set the event value as well as using the container.find() function to show the set value in the popup.

Comment: @TylerDahle, to get around that problem you'll need to also trigger the change event on the input. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah... I see. Thank you again for the help :)